# How to input the number of input in python

Tags: python

I want to input in inline

```
1. input number : 5  
2. 1 5 3 4 2
```

how to receive input for the number of inputs in python?

I've been tried like this:

```
num=int(input("inputs_num"))
mlist=[]
for i in range(num):
    n=int(input())
    mlist.append(n)
print(mlist)
```

I want to input in inline

Comment: `I want to input in lnline` - what exactly does that mean??

Comment: And BTW, your code seems to already answer the question in the title.

Comment: I think he wants to print the numbers in line.

Comment: If you want to be able to pass `1 5 3 4 2` as input at once rather than one at a time, get rid of the loop, take the input as a string, and then `split` and `map` to `int`. You will end up with a list of ints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to first get the whole line as a string, then split by spaces into a list, then convert each element into int.

So, the flow would look something like:

```
"1 5 3 4 2" -> Split -> ['1', '5', '3', '4', '2'] -> Map -> [1, 5, 3, 4, 2]
```

```
num=int(input("inputs_num"))
mstr = input().split() # ['1', '5', '3', '4', '2']
mlist=[]
for el in mstr:
  mlist.append(int(el))
```

Or a more pythonic way would be:

1. Using list comprehension

```
num=int(input("inputs_num"))
mlist=[int(i) for i in input().split()]
```

2. Using map

```
num=int(input("inputs_num"))
mlist=list(map(int, input().split()))
```

Comment: Thank you so much :) I understand!!

Answer (score 0):

**simple**

```
i = list(map(int, input("Numbers: ").split()))
print(i)
```

**It will accept multiple integers as input on a single line in Python3**

Comment: It's a simple solution!! Thank you so much